# Multi-process builds in Visual Studio 2010: Worth it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build, performance

I've started testing our C++ software with VS2010 and the build times are really bad (30-45 minutes, about double the VS2005 times). I've been reading about the /MP switch for multi-process compilation. Unfortunately, it is incompatible with some features that we use quite a bit like #import, incremental compilation, and precompiled headers.

Have you had a similar project where you tried the /MP switch after turning off things like precompiled headers? Did you get faster builds?

My machine is running 64-bit Windows 7 on a 4 core machine with 4 GB of RAM and a fast SSD storage. Virus scanner disabled and a pretty minimal software environment.

**Edit:** Martin and jdehaan pointed out that MP is not incompatible with precompiled headers. Details are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx).

Comment: I never got precompiled headers working, but using /MP gave a speedup of roughly 5x on a Core i7 (quad-core with hyperthreading).

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers? Do your libraries change between builds? Are you rebuilding anything more often than is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely **YES**. I worked on a large application which took around 35 minutes to build when something was modified (In Visual Studio). We used [IncrediBuild](http://www.xoreax.com/) for that (to speed up the compilation process, from 35 minutes to 5 minutes) - to be truly distributed. In your case it is possible that /MP switch will make some difference - but not that much compared to [distcc](http://distcc.samba.org/) (unix or compatible environment) or IncrediBuild.

Comment: 35 minutes using IncrediBuild? How long did builds take without it?

Comment: 35 minutes without IncrediBuild. With incredibuild (with 15-20 computers used) it took around 5-6 minutes (which is 7 times faster). I edited the answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that pch is incompatible with /MP?
You could certainly do a multi-core build on vs2008 with pch (although oddly only from within the IDE not on the commandline)

Comment: You're right, the pch should make no problems. It is created in a first non MP step and used read-only during the whole build for each compilation unit.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx again and noticed this time that MP is incompatible with creating the pch, not with using it. So Martin and jdehaan are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

My own experience is with VS2005 and VS2008.  With both of these, we turn off parallel builds since it doesn't work reliably for our large projects.  Also with both, enabling PCH gives great performance benefits.  Though if you don't use PCH with VS2008, you can really bad compile times as compared with VS2005.  I don't know how much of this is relevant to VS2010 though.

**EDIT:**  Had same problems with VS2010... but then we upgraded from WinXP to Win7 and all of our Visual Studio problems went away, with respect to both stability and performance.  In my previous ansswer, the parallel builds refers to msbuild project parallelism, and "large" in this case instead referred to large solutions.

Comment: Chris, could you please elaborate on your answer? We are looking at the `/MP` switch, and we're trying to find out whether it's affecting how "stable" Visual C++ is when building. You write: "we turn off parallel builds" -- Do you mean [*project* parallelism](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/08/tuning-c-build-parallelism-in-vs2010.aspx) or do you actually mean *compiler* parallelism as specified by the `/MP` flag?

Comment: And when you say "don't work ... large projects", do you mean "large" in the sense that you have a solution with many projects, or do you mean "large" in the sense that your single vcproj project(s) contain a huge number of cpp files?

Comment: @MartinBa:  I edited my answer, hopefully this helps with your questions.

Comment: thanks, that's really helpful. Funny, we've been using the project parallelism in VS2005 for years without problems (it's a VS default after all, so we used it and since it didn't break anything, it's still here) ON the other hand `/MP` is not the default, so we haven't used it across the board yet but are looking into it since it *really* speeds things up. There have been doubts whether we should use it, but from what you write, the project parallelism actually was responsible for your problems, not `/MP`, and that one we already use anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

Multi-machine builds (with IncrediBuild) were worth it for us. So a multi-process build on a single machine is quite likely to be worth it.